# Cutouts model resources?

Tags: 3d, laser-cutting

I am a fan of DIY stuff and have recently seen these [cardboard safari](http://www.cardboardsafari.com/shop/index.php) which looks pretty nice. I would like to try to do some of those myself but haven't found good cut out resources around and my own attempts never turn to be good looking (I suppose you a proper designer to know which lines are important or not for the model).

I might as well have to buy those, but that is not exactly "diy" then... But then again, I reckon these and more models would be fairly straight forward for someone into 3D.

Does anyone knows where could I find those in around the interwebs :)?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not quite what you wanted, but perhaps and alternative to it.

---

There is this website called http://www.shapeways.com/

It's a  lot like that cardboard safari website, except better ( In my opinion.. ).

They use different materials, but I think their materials ( which include stainless steel ) is an upgrade from what cardboard safari has to offer. ( unless that is what you're looking for. )

**They have these creator tools** http://www.shapeways.com/creator/ that will help you create your own objects. <sub>(*which is the main reason that made me want to answer.*)</sub>

Great thing about 3d printing is that you can do some pretty cool things. For example, moving parts and objects inside objects.

Plus the shop is filled with cool stuff designed by other people. ( Though they are pretty expensive. )

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can make a DIY aproach.

But there are several levels of DIY.

1) Do you know how to phisically sculpt? Great! Now you need to digitalize that.

You can use something like this: http://www.123dapp.com/catch But you need a lot of cleaning to do of the model.

2) Or do you want to sculpt from scrach in a 3d Program. https://www.blender.org/

https://www.sketchup.com/es/products/sketchup-make

http://pixologic.com/sculptris/

3) Or you can google for free 3D models https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+model+free

4) Now you need to make some slices. You need to import your object for example if it was made in sculpturis into blender and perform some bolean operations.

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html

This requires some practice in blender, becouse you need to solve specific issues regarding the geometry of the model. Also, importing the geometry sometimes can be buggy.

5) Now you can prepare your slices on an ortogonal view so you see them at the same scale, and use them as a template to print them. Something primitive as a screen capture can work.

Some cleaning of the images may be required. http://www.gimp.org/